# C code acting strange (Pointers)

Tags: c

My C function code keeps giving me errors, and I can't figure out whats wrong.

```
int * myfunc(int a)
{
    int * newNum, i;
    i = a*a;
    *newNum = i;
    return newNum;
}
```

Comment: `newNum` needs to point somewhere...

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224042/returning-a-pointer-to-an-automatic-variable

Comment: Returning dangling pointer ;-) Automatic variable i is out of scope after myfunc returns.

Comment: @FilipBulovic My eyes must be lying me because I can't see where the address of `i` is being taken :s

Comment: Do you mean return *newNum, that wouldn't give errors

Comment: @Diego huh, thanks, didn't even see that. So little code so many things to see.

Comment: What problems do you face?

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of memory or variables, automatic like in your function, static and manual. Automatic lasts while scope lasts. Static is if you declare it with static:

```
static int i;
```

It lives while program is alive. Like global variable. And finally manual where you use malloc and free to allocate and free memory. Naturally you would like to assign address of variable to pointer before return, like this:

```
int * newPointer = &i;
```

If variable is static it will keep value through function calls.
Code avoids warning from compiler about returning address of local variable via assigning address of local variable to pointer so it may be good idea to run on it some kind of tool like Lint or Splint, here is discussion about such [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995774/comparison-of-static-code-analysis-tools-in-linux%20tools)

Comment: You should elaborate on how the above helps the OP.

Comment: `malloc()`&friends manage _dynamically allocated_ memory, aka the **heap**. All named variables have to be defined "manually", the compiler only handles temps "automatically". And that is not "static", but global with different linkage.

Comment: @Olaf sure, problem here is that he is declaring pointer and would be assigning address of local variable to pointer, very nice way to avoid warning from compiler `function returns address of local variable`. Looking for tool which will do static analysis of code and help in such case.

Comment: I did get the question very well. However, you should use the proper terms in your explanation. That increases confusion for beginners. Just use the terms in the standard, they are widely accepted. I do not know about _your_ compiler, but gcc _does_ warn when returning a pointer to a local. Even without warnings enabled.

Comment: @Olaf still new around and not very clued up in ways how you people are trying to standardize. BTW I am also using gcc on Linux and it warns if you returning directly address but if you hide it with extra assignment it goes without warning, for that you need splint. I did double check.

Comment: That is not _us_ standardizing, but the [C ISO standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). Such answers should be well based on that. For the indirection: likely (true actually, I just verified), the compiler does not follow the chain. For such a tool, that should be easy to make it fail, too, with some more complicated approach. Never needed such a tool here.

Answer (score 1):

Look, `newNum` is a *pointer* to *integer*. So the purpose of `newNum` is to hold the `address` of any *integer*.

When you declared

```
int * newNum;
```

`newNum` is then pointing some garbage.

The following lines,

```
*newNum = i;
```

means the content of `newNum` will be updated by `i`. But did you forget, `newNum` holds some garbage address? Hence the value of `i` is assigned some garbage `location`.

You may try this:

```
/**
 * The following function will take an integer pointer from the caller. 
 * Its callers duty to check whether the pointer is initialed or not.
 */
void myfunc(int * newNum) {
    // the content of the newNum pointer points will be updated
    // as the memory address is sent here, we need not to return anything
    *newNum = (*newNum) * (*newNum);
}

int main() {
    int someInteger = 4;
    int *ptr = &someInteger;
    myfunc(ptr);
    printf("Content of the pointer: %d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

You will get the output like,

> Content of the pointer: 16

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I missed the mark! Ty, edited my answer.